# Switching Images in a Coinflip game

Tags: javascript, html, image, if-statement

I'm trying to switch images in javascript depending on the result of an `if`/`else` statement, but what I've tried doesn't work. How would I fix this?

**This is my script:**

```
var coin = document.getElementById(coin);
var coin = Math.round(Math.random());
var result;

if (coin === 1) {
document.getElementById("flip").src = "heads.jpg"
} else {
document.getElementById("coin").src = "tails.jpg"
};

document.write(result);
```

**And this is the html:**

```
 <h1>Make your decision!</h1>

 <img id="flip" src=".../img/heads.jpg">
 <img id="coin" src=".../img/tails.jpg">

 <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the full path if you are going to edit the src by javascrip eg:

```
if (coin === 1) {
document.getElementById("flip").src = ".../img/heads.jpg"
} else {
document.getElementById("coin").src = ".../img/tails.jpg"
};
```

However I would suggest using classes. Define a class for coin:

```
.coin {
    background-image: url(".../img/heads.jpg");
}
```

Then create another class for flipped:

```
.coin.flipped {
    background-image: url("../img/tails.jpg");
}
```

Then in your javascript code you would add the class or remove the class depending on if you want your image to be heads or tails. Or even Toggle class.
Please note this solution requires Jquery.

```
$(<elemselector>).AddClass("flipped ")
$(<elemselector>).RemoveClass("flipped ")
$(<elemselector>).ToggleClass("flipped ")
```

Comment: So, when you say add a class for coin, does that mean I go to my css file?

Comment: Yes, to use background-image, you do that with CSS. Ultimately, your HTML, for the coin, would only be <div id="coin" class="coin"> </div>.

Comment: You snuck some jQuery in there that @ChrisFernando might not have realised.

Comment: @JimW That's very true I will edit my answer to make that clear